# how to make sure the page is loading only after the jquery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsp page with jquery-ui somehow it's taking time to load . 
I have hide the dom and onload function I am writing the following code

```
setInterval(function(){
if(typeof jQuery.ui !=undefined )
 {
   $(document.body).css("visibility", "visible");
 }
},5000)
```

I don't want to run the function once condition get true , how to achieve it

Comment: You just write the jQuery reference line inside the body tag just after all the other tags inside the body instead of the head tag. It will work.

Answer (score 4):

Write your all code inside the:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" ); //Here you can put all the code
});
```

Once you DOM(Document object model) is ready then your js code will run, which is written inside the document ready function.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside a `$( document ).ready()` block. As shown below.

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});`

OR shorthand for $( document ).ready()

`$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});`

You may refer to this documentation for more information. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/